# limit grep context to a part of the result line

Tags: grep

I have a big sql dump with long lines and I would like to use grep to find a certain text string.

```
grep text_string filename.sql
```

returns the result lines which are huge and difficult to see where my text_string appears.
What I want to achieve is to get a result that contains lets say 50 characters to the left and 50 to the right of the search term (text_string).
Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `grep` with `-o` to get the desired portion only:

```
grep -Eo '.{,50}text_string.{,50}' filename.sql
```

Comment: That only works on lines that DO have 50+ characters on both sides of `text_string`.  Should be `grep -Eo '.{0,50}text_string.{0,50}' filename.sql` instead.

Comment: @cas oopss..missed that..fixed..